# Call a parent class's method from child class but don't see in the log file

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-logging

I would like to call a parent class's method from child class but I don't see the logging entry in the log file when I run the following command:

```
python.exe B.py
```

If I call the `printA()` method in the `A.py` code then I see the logging entry.

The following piece of Python code is `A.py` file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import logging
import logging.config
import yaml

with open('logging.yaml', 'r') as f:
    config = yaml.safe_load(f.read())
    logging.config.dictConfig(config)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class A:
    def __init__(self, name, value):
        self.name = name
        self.value = value

    def printA(self):
        logger.info('Name: {}'.format(self.name))
        logger.info('Value: {}'.format(self.value))
```

`B.py` file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from A import *
import logging
import logging.config
import yaml


with open('logging.yaml', 'r') as f:
    config = yaml.safe_load(f.read())
    logging.config.dictConfig(config)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, name, value):
        super(B, self).__init__(name, value + 1)      

b = B('Name', 1)
b.printA()
```

`logging.yaml` file:

```
version: 1
formatters:
  simple:
    format: '%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
handlers:
  console:
    class: logging.StreamHandler
    level: DEBUG
    formatter: simple
    stream: ext://sys.stdout
  debug_file_handler:
    class: logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler
    level: DEBUG
    formatter: simple
    filename: debug.log
    maxBytes: 10485760 # 10MB
    backupCount: 20
    encoding: utf8
root:
  level: DEBUG
  handlers: [console, debug_file_handler]
```

Actual result is an empty log file. The question is what should I change on my source code to make the logging function complete?
Will be grateful for any help.

Comment: Your code has syntax errors; `class` is *lowercase* in Python, and there is no `new` keyword (you create instances without `new`), and you didn't pass any arguments into the `B()` call, which requires 2 arguments. Please make sure that the code you post actually can be run and reproduces the issue.

Comment: is the code executing with out any errors?

Comment: @Nagashayan: yes, when I put these lines in A.py: 'a = A('Name', 1)
a.printA() ' then I see this: 2019-01-04 16:20:52,164 - __main__ - INFO - Name: Name
2019-01-04 16:20:52,164 - __main__ - INFO - Value: 1

Comment: The class `A.A` uses `A.logger`; class `B.B`, since it doesn't define its own `printA` method, *also* uses `A.logger`, not `B.logger`. Globals in Python are *module*-level globals, not process-level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are configuring and re-configuring the `logging` module, and each time you call `logging.config.dictConfig()` you leave the `disable_existing_loggers` parameter to `dictConfig()` to `True`. See the [*Dictionary Schema Details* section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.config.html#dictionary-schema-details) of the documentation:

> `disable_existing_loggers` - whether any existing loggers are to be disabled. This setting mirrors the parameter of the same name in `fileConfig()`. If absent, this parameter defaults to True. This value is ignored if `incremental` is True.

So each time you call `dictConfig()` any `logging.Logger()` instances are being *disabled*.

Your code works if you only call `dictConfig()` *once*, before you use `logging.getLogger(__name__)` to create your single `Logging()` object. But when you expanded to two modules, your `from A import *` line imports `A`, executes `dictConfig()` and creates a `Logger()` before control returns to the `B` module, which then again runs `dictConfig()` (the `logger` reference you create in `B` is otherwise unused anywhere).

You only need to configure logging *once*, preferably as early as possible from the main entry point (the script you run with Python), and if your code has already created `Logger()` instances you want to continue to use, you either need to set `incremental` to True (but understand [that only a [subset of your configuration](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.config.html#logging-config-dict-incremental) will be applied then), or set `disable_existing_loggers` to `False`.

Remember that you can always update the dictionary you load from the `.yaml` file, so you could just use:

```
config['disable_existing_loggers'] = False
```

before you pass `config` to `logging.config.dictConfig()`.

I'd use a `if __name__ == '__main__':` guard to ensure that you only configure logging at that point. Don't run top-level code in a module that alters global configuration without such a guard:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # this module is used as a script, configure logging
    with open('logging.yaml', 'r') as f:
        config = yaml.safe_load(f.read())
    # do not disable any logger objects already created before this point
    config['disable_existing_loggers'] = False
    logging.config.dictConfig(config)
```